# X11VNC: TLS Handshake Failure on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, vnc, openssl, remmina

I had the x11vnc server installed on Ubuntu 18.04, now I have upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.

I was able to connect to vnc server from Remmina client without any error, however after up-gradation to Ubuntu 22.04- I started getting `TLS Handshake Failed error`.

I have tried to modify `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf` configuration with below as Ubuntu 22.04 have openssl 3.0, but still no luck.

```
[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
```

After seeing logs on server, I've noticed there is mismatch between client and server's Cipher-

```
SSL: error:0A0000C1:SSL routines::no shared cipher
```

I don't have much exposure on these stuff, could someone please suggest to fix above issues with Remmina clients.

PS: I've tried with other clients as well like TigerVNC Viewer and RealVNC but still not worked.